# Threading with Flask to monitor serial data

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, raspberry-pi

I am implementing a web-server with the help of flask on Raspberry Pi, so far i was able to get the date,time & serial data  working.

I want to create thread where the serial data is continuously monitored and mathematical operations are performed on the received data and that data is transferred to flask app

the current program is as follows

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

import datetime
import serial
import threading

area1_light=0
area1_temp=0

area2_light=0
area2_temp=0

serial_rxdata='L1234T029'
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',9600)


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def WSN():

    global area1_light
    global area1_temp

    global area2_light
    global area2_temp

    global serial_rxdata


    serial_rxdata=[]
    serial_rxdata=ser.readline()

    area1_light=serial_rxdata[1:5]
    area1_temp=serial_rxdata[7:10]
    now=datetime.datetime.now()
    timeString = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    templateData = {
        'title' : 'webdata!',
        'time' : timeString,
        'a1light' :area1_light,
        'a1temp': area1_temp,
        }
    return render_template('web.html', **templateData)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

during this the website is unable to load till the data is received,
and the serial data communication will be continuous with other devices ,
how should i do that?
i am unable to do this program using threads.

Comment: That is a complex topic, and nobody can provide a simple answer. You need to read about concurrency architectures, about how to decouple system components (with a feeder/worker model for instance, involving message queues), and possibly about how to use long-polling or websockets in order to have fine-grained control about *when* you send *which* information to the web browser.